# Como alinhar texto na vertical ao lado de imagem?

Tags: html, css

Olá, o que falta nesse código para deixar o texto alinhado na vertical ao lado da imagem, sendo que cada uma das tres div´s menores tem uma imagem e um texto.

```css
* {
 margin:0; padding:0;
}
body
{
background: url("../IMAGENS/Art-photography-winter-snow-trees-bench_1366x768.jpg") no-repeat bottom center scroll;
overflow:hidden;

}
#corpo-form
{
 position:relative; width:480; margin:130px auto 0px auto; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#corpo-form div
{
 display:block;
 height:100px;
 margin:10px;
 border-radius:5px;
 outline:none;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.menu{
 line-height:100px;
}
.menu img {
 height:100px; width:100px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <title>Projeto</title>
 <link  rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/css_main.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id ="corpo-form">
 <form  method="POST">
 
  <h1>Menu</h1>

  <div class="menu">
   <img src="./IMAGENS/iconfinder_03_188727.png";
   <label class="configuracao">Configuraçoes do Aplicativo</label>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <img src="./IMAGENS/lendo.jpg";
   <label class="leitura">Leitura</label>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <img src="./IMAGENS/lupa.png";
   <label class="pesquisa">Pesquisa</label>
  </div>
  
  <br>
 </form>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem algumas forma diferentes de fazer isso, mas no sue caso eu sugiro colocar na `#corpo-form div` um `display:flex;` com `align-items: center;` isso vai alinhar o texto na vertical ao lado da imagem, e vai ser mais fácil de tratar a responsividade no futuro.

```css
* {
 margin:0; padding:0;
}
body
{
background: url("../IMAGENS/Art-photography-winter-snow-trees-bench_1366x768.jpg") no-repeat bottom center scroll;
overflow:hidden;

}
#corpo-form
{
 position:relative; width:480; margin:130px auto 0px auto; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#corpo-form div
{
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
 height:100px;
 margin:10px;
 border-radius:5px;
 outline:none;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.menu{
 line-height:100px;
}
.menu img {
 height:100px; width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id ="corpo-form">
 <form  method="POST">
 
  <h1>Menu</h1>

  <div class="menu">
   <img src="./IMAGENS/iconfinder_03_188727.png";>
   <label class="configuracao">Configuraçoes do Aplicativo</label>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <img src="./IMAGENS/lendo.jpg";>
   <label class="leitura">Leitura</label>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <img src="./IMAGENS/lupa.png";>
   <label class="pesquisa">Pesquisa</label>
  </div>
  
  <br>
 </form>
 
</div>
```

Comment: hugocsl...funcionou! vlw.

Comment: @Fernandes legal que deu certo ai 